# задержка в выполнении кода, domReady

Tags: javascript, dom

Приветствую, сообщество. Следующий код добавляет к `body` класс `loaded`. Как изменить его так, чтобы класс добавлялся спустя две секунды после выполнения условия(здесь - генерация DOM).

```js
function domReady() {
    document.body.className += " loaded";
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", arguments.callee, false);
        domReady();
    }, false);
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function() {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            document.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", arguments.callee);
            domReady();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: setTimeout(function (){}, 2000) пробовали ?

Comment: @RomanKozin, честно говоря - нет. У меня со скриптами совсем туго. Не могли бы вы оформить ответом? Эта строка выглядит логичным решением.

Comment: вызывай свою функцию в етой обгортке `setTimeout(function (){domReady();}, 2000);` даже можно написать короче `setTimeout(domReady, 2000);` - так должно тоже сработать

Comment: @ИванmalginovdesignМальгинов вы тоже из тех кто думает, что java == javascript?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский никогда не задумывался на этот счет..*стыд*

Comment: @ИванmalginovdesignМальгинов ответ давно оформил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нативный **JS**:

```js
function ready(){
    document.body.className += ' loaded'
}
    
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    setTimeout(ready, 2000);
});
```

**jQuery**

```js
$(function (){
    setTimeout(function () { $('body').addClass('loaded') }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: оба варианта не верны: первый параметр setTimeout должен быть функцией.

Comment: Уважаемый, посмотрите внимательно на аргументы вместо того, чтобы сразу ставить минус и сами запустите код

Comment: @Grundy https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: Именно. после анонимной правки недочеты устранены. До нее было `setTimeout(ready(), 2000);` - что очевидно неверно. и минус абсолютно заслуженный. за совет, который не работает.